# Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist Open File

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I imported a project downloaded from GitHub into my Android Studio project as module.
The "Import module..." wizard worked fine, but when the Adroid Studio tried to rebuild the project, it returned me this error:

```
Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist Open File
```

The error is related to this line in the "build.gradle" file of the imported module:

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
```

I tried to add "ext" section in the project "build.gradle" like this:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion 26
}
```

But in this way I receive a new error:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileSdkVersion()' Possible causes: ...
```

Comment: Add your build.gradle

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In your **top-level** file use:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
}
```

In your `module/build.gradle` file use:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  ...
}
```

Comment: If I add the block "ext { compileSdkVersion = 26 }" in the top-level (build.gradle), the build action return me this error: 

Error:(26, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'mySticker'.
> Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [26] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.

Comment: Are you sure about the = sign? Because this error happens if you add compileSdkVersion 26 without sign

Comment: What is the 'top level file'?

Comment: @jeancode the build.gradle in the root of the project

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: Thanks that it solved for properties `compileSdkVersion` but it gives the same error but on another property `buildToolsVersion`. I assume that I can apply same way for this property too?

Comment: @Isaac Yes you can.

Comment: For those who not on Android: it is needed to set _project.ext_ but not just _ext_

Comment: sorry i cannot find "top-level" file. is there any other name it has?. mind telling us here?

Comment: @jerinho The top level file is the build.gradle that you can find in the root of the project.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440756/cannot-get-property-compilesdkversion-on-extra-properties

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I followed all your steps mentioned in the answer. So I have made changes in `android -> app->build.gradle file` and `android-> build.gradle` file is it correct ?

Comment: @Isaac  it solved for properties compileSdkVersion but it gives the same error for another property buildToolsVersion after build tools it says minSdkVersion why am I getting all this ? Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440756/cannot-get-property-compilesdkversion-on-extra-properties

Comment: it will be better for freshers like me  if you give an example for rootProject and  top-level in your answer. Thanks BTW it works for me

Comment: I also get this `Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments`, no matter what I do. Now I hardcoded the version everywhere. Can somebody give an example with whole file contents, please?!

Answer (score 2):

## Another way:

Your `build.gradle` in **top-level** module

```
ext {
    minSdk = 21
    targetSdk = 29
    compileSdk = 29
    buildTools = '29.0.3'
}
```

Your `build.gradle` in **app** module

```
android {
    def buildConfig = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    compileSdkVersion buildConfig.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion buildConfig.buildTools
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion buildConfig.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion buildConfig.targetSdk
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In build.gradle you need to write compilesdkversion under `android` tag as in this example:

`android {
..
  compileSdkVersion 26 // 26 is an example
..}`

By the way. You can build that module as library then import it into your project as `.aar` file.

Answer (score -2):

Change your .gradle `android` part to this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your App id"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```