# REACT NATIVE Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I'm getting this error in React Native.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653560/cannot-get-property-compilesdkversion-on-extra-properties-extension-as-it-does?rq=1) says to put

```
ext {
compileSdkVersion = 26
```

}

in the 'top level file'. What is the 'top level file' for this in React Native?

`module/build.gradle` already has

`android {
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion...`

Answer (score 6):

React Native android has two build.gradle files

```
// android/build.gradle
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}

//android/app/build.gradle
android {
   compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
}
```

Comment: It is still giving: compileSdkVersion is not specified.

Comment: this data is already there, and still not working