# Cannot get property compileSdkVersion on extra properties?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native app on windows. When I do `react-native run-android` I get error `compileSdkVersion on extra properties` see screenshot 1 below. To solve that issue in android folder ->build.gradle I added following code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
}
```

And in android->app->build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion  <--Added this line
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.faithcircle"
    minSdkVersion 16
```

But if I do above changes it doesn't work why so ? It gives me new error see screenshot 2 below.

Screenshot1:

[image]

Screenshot2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android need the deployed version of sdk..
Thats why you need to first deploy the sdk in your project..
It will create the android folder in your app..
That will have one build.gradle...
And there you can pass your buildsdkversion parameters and all