# Flutter gradle.build error: Could not get unknown property 'compileSdkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I Manually added a flutter project to AndroidStudioProjects directory.

I started getting this error

error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\projectName\android\app\build.gradle' line: 29

 * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'compileSdkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.
```

build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion     // FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.newweather"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried these, they didnt work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60565001/17740672

changing compileSdkVersion to a constant number

jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj

jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj

Comment: From where you are getting value in flutter.compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: Please have a look at this. [Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653560/cannot-get-property-compilesdkversion-on-extra-properties-extension-as-it-does)

Answer (score 5):

Try the commands

> flutter clean

and

> flutter upgrade

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error after moving some Java files or directories around, then you may have confused Android Studio, as the IDE caches information about your project’s structure. To clear Android Studio’s cache and bring it out of its state of confusion, `select ‘File > Invalidate Caches / Restart’ and then click the ‘Invalidate and Restart’ button.` Clean and rebuild your project.