# In my Android app how can I define properties that won't get checked into the version control system?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to define an API key as property in my Adroid app written in Kotlin so that it won't get checked into github.

I have found several sources of inspiration, as in
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-safely-store-credentials-in-android-projects-using-gradle-properties-8cf500561095

and faced errors like

```
Cannot get property 'xyz' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

[Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist Open File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653560/cannot-get-property-compilesdkversion-on-extra-properties-extension-as-it-does)

but with no simple solution.

I'd like to share how I eventually implemented it. Please comment and or suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file `secret.properties` at the root of your project. This file will store properties that should remain secret. Add it to `.gitignore` so it won't be checked into the version control system (e.g. github).
In addition, we want to be able to set or overwrite those properties with using environment variables.

Add a buildscript at the top of your app's `build.gradle` to read the `secret.properties` file.

Call `buildConfigField()` in the `defaultConfig` section. You must provide a string wrapped inside escaped double quotes ([see example here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-properties-with-the-manifest)).

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    def propertiesFile = rootProject.file('secret.properties')
    if (propertiesFile.exists()) {
        properties.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
    }
    def localPropertyValue = properties.getProperty('custom.variable')
    def systemEnvValue = System.getenv('CUSTOM_VARIABLE')
    rootProject.ext.custom_variable = systemEnvValue != null ? systemEnvValue : localPropertyValue
}

plugins {
    ...
}

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField("String","CUSTOM_VARIABLE", "\"${rootProject.ext.custom_variable}\"")
    }
    ...
}
```

**secret.properties**

```
custom.variable=my_custom_variable_value_here
```

Remember to click on the "Sync now" button at the top of your `build.gradle` file after you've edited and saved it.
[image]

Finally, rebuild your project and the new property becomes available using `BuildConfig.CUSTOM_VARIABLE` throughout your code.